# C++ My program keeps only calling the default constructor instead of my constructor with parameters

Tags: c++, constructor

Hey guys so I was working on a basic program that requires us in practicing constructors but I dont understand why I'm getting the wrong output. Whenever I run the code I always get bob as my output instead of the other bobs. If someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it that would be great!

The following is in my .h file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class creature{
public:
    creature();
    creature(int a);//initalizes the name of the creature based on what the user chooses(1,2, or 3 determines the monster name)
    string getName();//accessor for the name
    string getColor();//accessor for the color
 private:
    string name;
    string color;
  };
```

The following is in one of my cpp file:

```
creature::creature(){
    name="bob";
    color="black";

}

creature::creature(int a)
{
    if(a==1)
        name="bob_1";
    else if(a==2)
        name="bob_2";
    else if(a==3)
        name="bob_3";
}

string creature::getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

The following is in one of my cpp file:

```
#include "creature.h"
int main()
{

    creature monster;

    int choice;


    cout << "Enter 1 2 or 3 to choose your creature" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    if (input == 1)
    {
        creature(input);
        cout << "Congratulations you have chosen " << monster.getName() <<;
    }

    else if (input == 2)
    {
        creature(choice);
        cout << "Congratulations you have chosen " << monster.getName() <<;
    }

    else if (input == 3)
    {
        creature(input);
        cout << "Congratulations you have chosen " << monster.getName() <<;
    }

}
```

Comment: 'creature monster;' - Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
creature monster;
```

creates monster with the parameterless constructor. Then:

```
 creature(choice);
```

just creates and immediately destroys a nameless temporary of the same type, but in no way it modifies the original monster.

You probably want something like:

```
monster = creature(choice);
```

Or maybe the variable should be instead a pointer, maybe a smart one:

```
std::unique_ptr<creature> monster;
...
monster.reset(new creature(choice));
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKS NOW. Thank you and vsoftco for your explanation I understand now and got the code to work!

Answer (score 4):

You already created the `monster` in the line

```
creature monster;
```

which is using the default constructor. It looks like you need a "factory" function to create creatures on demand, because otherwise

```
creature(input);
```

is just creating a temporary, not related to the original `monster`. In your case you may also use the compiler-generated copy constructor and write

```
monster = creature(input);
```

so your original `monster` is being re-assigned the newly created one.